# New TextBox not being created in WindowsForms

Tags: c#, textbox, windows-forms-designer

```
private struct TextBoxLocation //Location
        {
            public int LocationX; 
            public int LocationY;
        }

        private TextBoxLocation location = new TextBoxLocation
        {
            LocationX = 210,
            LocationY = 52
        };
        
        private void FolderPathTextBox(object item, int textBoxNumber)
        {
            TextBox box = new TextBox();
            box.Location = new Point(location.LocationX, location.LocationX);
            box.Name = "folderPathTextBox" + textBoxNumber;
            box.Text = folderPath + item.ToString();
            //box.BackColor = FoldersToClear.BackColor;
            box.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            this.Controls.Add(box);
            box.Focus();

            location.LocationY += 15; //Needs to be increment by 15 everytime
```

I've been working on my project and I need it to create new **TextBox** for each new object in CheckListbox. Location's are fine, because I tested it with new TextBox in Form1.cs[Design].

My question is, what am I missing here, or why isn't it working?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example, as per the Help Centre. Your code looks OK at a glance but the actual issue may well be somewhere that you haven't shown us. For one thing, you say that you're adding multiple TextBoxes based on a CheckedListBox but there's no evidence of that in the code.

Comment: Please tell me you have already done the minimal work to be sure this method is called. You know, the usual things, like setting a debugger breakpoint in the first line and then running the code until it stops at the breakpoint.

Comment: Everything is done. Everything goes through. Just that not appearing. Loop goes through 3 times, and method gets called and executed, just on textbox to be seen, with any text.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was that I was putting **TextBox** behind my **CheckListbox** component, and I had to include **Controls** of CheckListbox first in order for it to be seen on top of **CheckListbox**.

```
this.Controls.Add(FoldersToClear);
```

Or

```
this.FoldersToClear.Controls.Add(box); //FoldersToClear is CheckListbox
```